# fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to show 25 of the songs I have in my library. This is my code:

```
var allSongsArray: [MPMediaItem] = []
let songsQuery = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 25 //allSongsArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
    let items = allSongsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell?.textLabel?.text = items.title
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = items.artist
    cell?.imageView?.image = items.artwork?.imageWithSize(imageSize)

    return cell!
}
```

When I run this, it crashes, because:

> fatal error: Index out of range

I tried to change the `numberOfRowsInSection` to `allSongsArray.count`, but it ends up with the same error.

Comment: You should definitely return `allSongsArray.count` rather than a literal number; before the query has executed the array will contain 0 items.  What index are you trying to access when the exception occurs?

Comment: It will certainly crash with 25 hard-coded as the number of rows, as your array is declared as empty. I doubt that it will crash with `allSongsArray.count`, but it won't show anything...

Comment: Oh yes, you´re right. It don´t show anything. How can i show 25 songs? @Grimxn

Comment: Add (append) the `MPMediaItem` objects to `allSongsArray` and reload the table view

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should return `allSongsArray.count` and to avoid being returned empty cells use `yourTableView.reloadData` after you fill your `allSongsArray`.

Answer (score 3):

When you first create the array it is empty. Hence, it will give you out of bound error.

Try to return the count of the songs array instead.

1st you need to get the data into the array and then update the table view.

Here is a sample code:

```
@IBAction private func refresh(sender: UIRefreshControl?) {
        if myArray.count > 0 {
              self.tableView.reloadData()
              sender?.endRefreshing()
        } else {
              sender?.endRefreshing()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried, but then the cells are empty. How can i fill the cells with my songs?

Comment: first you need a function to fill up the songs array. and they you need to add refresh ability to you class. in the refresh action just update the table using tableView.reloadData()

Comment: check the code above. Please note u can add refresh ability from the storyboard

Answer (score 3):

In case your app crashes in

```
 let items = allSongsArray[indexPath.row]
```

as you check if the allSongsArray.count, u can safe guard it by making sure that the [indexPath.row] doesn't exceed your array count. so u can write a simple if condition as;

```
if allSongsArray.count > 0 && indexPath.row < allSongsArray.count {

  //Do the needful

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please return the actual array count instead of static

```
return allsongsarray.count
```

Answer (score 0):

For folks looking for a solution to swiping on a filtered list, you need to provide the section as well as the row or xcode throws this error.

```
func swipe(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let myRow = filteredList[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
}
```

not

```
func swipe(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let myRow = filteredList[indexPath.row]
}
```