# Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range when index is less then array count

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, audio-streaming

I am getting error Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range on

```
func ReaderConverterCallback(_ converter: AudioConverterRef,
                             _ packetCount: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>,
                             _ ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>,
                             _ outPacketDescriptions: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>?>?,
                             _ context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> OSStatus {
    let reader = Unmanaged<Reader>.fromOpaque(context!).takeUnretainedValue()

    //
    // Make sure we have a valid source format so we know the data format of the parser's audio packets
    //
    guard let sourceFormat = reader.parser.dataFormat else {
        return ReaderMissingSourceFormatError
    }

    //
    // Check if we've reached the end of the packets. We have two scenarios:
    //     1. We've reached the end of the packet data and the file has been completely parsed
    //     2. We've reached the end of the data we currently have downloaded, but not the file
    //
    let packetIndex = Int(reader.currentPacket)
    let packets = reader.parser.packets
    let isEndOfData = packetIndex >= packets.count - 1
    if isEndOfData {
        if reader.parser.isParsingComplete {
            packetCount.pointee = 0
            return ReaderReachedEndOfDataError
        } else {
            return ReaderNotEnoughDataError
        }
    }

    //
    // Copy data over (note we've only processing a single packet of data at a time)
    //
    let packet = packets[packetIndex]    <--------- Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range on 
    var data = packet.0
    let dataCount = data.count
    ioData.pointee.mNumberBuffers = 1
    ioData.pointee.mBuffers.mData = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount: dataCount, alignment: 0)
    _ = data.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (bytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) in
        memcpy((ioData.pointee.mBuffers.mData?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self))!, bytes, dataCount)
    }
    ioData.pointee.mBuffers.mDataByteSize = UInt32(dataCount)

    //
    // Handle packet descriptions for compressed formats (MP3, AAC, etc)
    //
    let sourceFormatDescription = sourceFormat.streamDescription.pointee
    if sourceFormatDescription.mFormatID != kAudioFormatLinearPCM {
        if outPacketDescriptions?.pointee == nil {
            outPacketDescriptions?.pointee = UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>.allocate(capacity: 1)
        }
        outPacketDescriptions?.pointee?.pointee.mDataByteSize = UInt32(dataCount)
        outPacketDescriptions?.pointee?.pointee.mStartOffset = 0
        outPacketDescriptions?.pointee?.pointee.mVariableFramesInPacket = 0
    }
    packetCount.pointee = 1
    reader.currentPacket = reader.currentPacket + 1

    return noErr;
}
```

even if there is packetIndex is less then packets.count.

[image]

**Note:** Please compare both question before marking it duplicate. Reference possible duplicate doesn't show that index of array is less than array count.

**I am using this https://github.com/syedhali/AudioStreamer/ library for playing audio from url.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260542/fatal-error-index-out-of-range Seems like here is your case.

Comment: Can you put log on root and analyse if this method is calling multiple times and your packets are changing on line     let packets = reader.parser.packets

Comment: @user3279258 Can you please how it same with other ? The question you are referencing is not showing that index is less then array count and error come.

Comment: @ChatarVeerSuthar yes this method is keep calling but how is it possible that variable changes it's value just after I print the index and array count

Comment: @VarunNaharia i know you printed it on line 54, but can you to a `po packets.count` and `po packetIndex` in console on crash?

Comment: yes, it's possible, as its in callback thread, which gets calls before your next lines comes in. You can put Delay in calling of methods from original, or you can use sync call, instead of async.

In Sync, it will wait until previous calling get finished

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Multi-Thread problem. According to the printed logs, the index seems ok, but another thread may change the data 'packets', that causes the crash. Please consider locking data-related operations between threads.

Additional analyzation: according to the following lines, `packets` may be shared between threads.

```
let reader = Unmanaged<Reader>.fromOpaque(context!).takeUnretainedValue()
//......
let packets = reader.parser.packets
```

**Suggestion**: check if somewhere the `Unmanaged<Reader>` change the `parser.packets`, and make a lock strategy.

Comment: Thanks for understanding question I'll try and let you know if is work.

Comment: I tried but it does't work but I think you pointed me in right direction.

Comment: I add a suggestion to the answer, holp it helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks I am checking