# Fatal error: Index out of range (on cellForRowAt tableView func)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to assign values to some text and getting a fatal error:

`Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`

Here is my func:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if (indexPath.row < 5) {
            let cell:TaskCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell
            let taskIndex = indexPath.row
            print(taskIndex)
    
            if let task = card?.tasks[taskIndex] {
                cell.taskText.text = task.text
                cell.taskBtn.isSelected = task.complete
            }
            
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell:GratefulCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GratefulCell", for: indexPath) as! GratefulCell
            let gratefulIndex = indexPath.row
            print(gratefulIndex)
            cell.gratefulNum.text = String(gratefulIndex - 4)
            
            if let grateful = card?.gratefuls[gratefulIndex] {   <-------ERROR HERE.
                cell.gratefulText.text = grateful.text
            }
            
            cell.selectionStyle = .none

            return cell
        }
    }
```

I'm filling out text in every box available on my screen.
(9 total, 5 for tasks, 4 for gratefuls)

When I print(taskIndex) and print(gratefulIndex) I get:

```
task 1
task 2
task 3
task 4
grateful 5
grateful 6
grateful 7
grateful 8
```

When I save my "card" (which is a single screen holding tasks and gratefuls) then go to reopen the card I get

```
task 0
task 1
task 2
task 3
task 4
grateful 5
```

Then it dies... any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm sure its starring right at me but I can't figure it out. If you need any additional information please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fatal error: Index out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260542/fatal-error-index-out-of-range)

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff I read that thread and I don't believe it's my issue. I'm getting the correct array when I save my card. However when I go to reopen it I get a different array and the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you should use a sectioned table view with 2 sections, one for tasks, and one for "gratefuls". The row will start at 0 for each section, so you can use the row number to index into both your tasks and your gratefuls.

The way you've written your table view code, your first gratefuls will try to index into your gratefuls array at index `card?.tasks.count`.

You need to start at index 0 of your gratefuls. If you're going to do it all with one section, change this bit:

```
        let tasksCount = card?.tasks.count ?? 0
        if indexPath.row < tasksCount {
           // Tasks code.
        } else {
            let cell:GratefulCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GratefulCell", for: indexPath) as! GratefulCell
            // Below is the change to make your gratefulIndex start at 0, the first item in your array `gratefuls`.
            let gratefulIndex = indexPath.row - tasksCount
            print("gratefuls[\(gratefulIndex)]")
            cell.gratefulNum.text = String(gratefulIndex + 1)
            if let grateful = card?.gratefuls[gratefulIndex] {  
                cell.gratefulText.text = grateful.text
            }
            
            cell.selectionStyle = .none

            return cell
        }
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error but I appreciate you response! You've got my brain thinking differently now, I know it has to be an issue with the two indexes...OR I'm not reloading the data so it doesn't find text in the cells.... either way, I'll keep poking at it. Once again thanks!

Comment: Actually...that did work. I had `(card?.gratefuls.count ?? 0)`  rather than `tasks`. Thank you...so. much. Onto the next bugs!

Comment: Note that I cleaned up the code above some. (Still untested.)

Comment: Very appreciative Duncan! I'm sort of self teaching myself all of this so I get hung up more than not.